# How to create a char buffer in structure?

Tags: c

I want to create a structure with field color, that can consider n characters. So, how can i create it without certain size:

```
struct A {
    int width;
    int height;
    int length;
    char name[50];
    **char color[];**
};
```

```
struct A a = { 10, 20, 30, "Hello", "Red" };
```

I tried test it without structure and all is working, why ?

```
char p[] = "Hallo";
```

Comment: Use `malloc()`/`calloc()`.

Comment: When using `malloc`, you can either put a pointer in the `struct` that points to the memory allocated by `malloc`, or you can use a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member).

Comment: The line `char p[] = "Hallo";` is equivalent to `char p[6] = "Hallo";`. Therefore, you assumption is incorrect that the array is not being created with a certain size.

Comment: If the size of the string is less than 16 bytes, then just use an array with automatic storage duration. Allocation with `malloc` will likely have a minimum allocation size of `16` bytes anyway (or whatever the memory alignment is on your architecture), so you are not saving memory allocating smaller units. Besides, a pointer will require 8-bytes to begin with (or 4-bytes on some architectures), so a small fixed array if the colors fit is likely the most efficient route (both from a storage and code-complexity standpoint)0

Comment: If number and name of colors are fixed, I'd suggest to use ```enum``` in conjunction with ```typedef```to define a type that lists all the possible colors, so that you can refer to each color by its name in the rest of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straight forward way to do this on a modern system with an operating system is to use [malloc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html)/[free](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/free.3.html):

```
struct A {
    int width;
    int height;
    int length;
    char name[50];

    char *color;
};
```

Here `color` is just a pointer type to a memory location that is of type `char`.

How to use it?

Use `malloc` to dynamically allocate memory and save the returned address in `color` like this:

```
struct A var;

var.color = malloc(sizeof(char) * n);
```

Where `n` is the number of `char`acters you want to allocate.

`sizeof(char)` here is superfluous since it's guaranteed to be `1`.

However, I included it because if you wanted to, say, allocate an array of `int`egers you would use:

```
malloc(sizeof(int) * n)
```

`sizeof(int)` is not always the same value, it depends on your architecture.

Also, in all cases you need to keep track of the size of your allocated memory yourself. There isn't a standard function that will tell you how big a buffer is by simply passing a pointer.

Note that `malloc` can return `NULL` (a pointer that you should never dereference) in case something went wrong, so you need to check the return value of `malloc` before using it).

When you're done with the memory, you must `free` the allocated memory like this:

```
free(var.color);
// do not use the value of var.color after this
```

**Don't** use value of `var.color` after passing it to `free`, otherwise the behaviour is undefined (use-after-free).

If you don't `free` your memory you may risk a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

Answer (score 1):

Following up on my comment to the OP, and **assuming the number and names of the acceptable colors are known in advance**, here's an example where I used `enum` in conjunction with `typedef` to define a type that lists all the possible colors allowed by the program, so that the user can refer to each color by its name in the rest of the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef enum{
RED = 0,
GREEN = 1,
BLUE = 2
} Colors;

struct A {
    int width;
    int height;
    int length;
    char name[50];
    Colors color;
};

int main(void){
    struct A a = { 10, 20, 30, "Hello", RED };
    printf("%d\n",BLUE+GREEN);
}
```

Needless to say, other colors can be added to the `enum` definition.

It's also worth noting that `enum` associates an integer to each item; arithmetics becomes possible, as in `BLUE + GREEN`, which yields `3` in the code sample above.

Answer (score 0):

You can have `color` field as a pointer to `char` and create a `enum` whose elements indicate the colours and use them as designated initialiser in an array of strings which will have the color names. The `enum` elements can be used as index in color name array to get the appropriate color name and which can be assigned to structure `color` field, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum colors {
    WHITE = 0,
    BLACK,
    RED,
    GREEN,
    BLUE,
    MAX_COLOR
};

char * color_names[MAX_COLOR + 1] = {
            [WHITE] = "White",
            [BLACK] = "Black",
            [RED]   = "Red",
            [GREEN] = "Green",
            [BLUE]  = "Blue",
            [MAX_COLOR] = NULL
        };

struct A {
    int width;
    int height;
    int length;
    char name[50];
    char * color;
};

int main (void) {
    struct A a = { 10, 20, 30, "Hello", color_names[RED] };
    printf ("a.color : %s\n", a.color);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out
a.color : Red
```